# Geetting 2 empty lines at end of csv

Tags: javascript, vue.js, csv

im using vue-blob-json-csv to export data as csv file, i dont have any empty lines in the data (checking with console), but once i export, 2 empty lines join at the end of the file.

here is my script

```
export default {
  name: "DownloadCSV",

  data() {
    return {
      fields: [],
      randomizedNames: localStorage.getItem("randomizedArr"),
    };
  },
  created() {
    const parsedArr = JSON.parse(this.randomizedNames);
    let item = parsedArr[0].parsed;

    console.log(item);
    this.fields.push(item);

    console.log(this.fields);
  },
  methods: {},
};




this is my HTML

  <vue-blob-json-csv
    :fields="this.fields"
    fileName="random names"
    class="primary"
    tag-name="v-btn"
    file-type="csv"
    title="download csv file"
    :data="JSON.parse(this.randomizedNames)"
    confirm="Do you want to download it?"
  ></vue-blob-json-csv>
```

any ideas on how to approach this issue?

Comment: So you never get empty lines in this log statement: `console.log(item);`

Comment: exactly i just get the data, which is ready to download with no empty lines

Comment: Snippet does not work.

Comment: No intention for Snippet. is removed now